# Raspberry Pi or Similar to Go

Tags: pi-2

This question might be too broad, but I need a starting Point. I'm trying to find a little computer that can run with a battery for at least 24h, just using the cpu + wifi. Is raspberry suited for that or are there any better options? I basically want to use it as a control unit, to control other devices and log information in realtime. (For Filmsets)

Comment: You need to decide WHAT you actually want to do - you could probably do this with an Arduino.

Comment: You haven't given nearly enough information here for someone to give you any kind of a valid answer. What kind of task is this going to complete? What sized battery?

Answer (score 1):

I think Pi is suitable for your need

- Low power comsumption
- Pi 2/3's CPU is enough for your tasks

I recommend you to try **Pi Zero Wireless** or **Banana/Nano/Orange Pi** from other manufacturers.

Comment: Oh that looks interesting, didn't know about the Pi Zero Wireless

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try Pi Zero W. I have used it with my 10000 mAH battery pack and it ran for well over a day.

Answer (score 1):

Another vote for Pi Zero W.
I have one here that I just measured that takes 80ma at idle, so 1920mah in 24hrs.

But note that you can't get the onboard wifi to act as an access point. To make an access point you can use a non-W zero and a supported USB wifi device.

I've just measured a Pi Zero with usb wifi and it idles at 100ma, though jumps to 160ma when I ping it!

Also note that a Pi won't cope with anything that is rapidly changing. 
Eg I receive data from wireless thermometers as a bitstream but had to use an arduino to do that. The arduino does the receiving and decoding (and that is all it does) and then passes it to a Pi Zero which is the brains of the operation.